# Custom form fields required but not shown

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, validation

I'm trying to fix a overriden form, which has seven fields required by the form validator, but don't displayed. I found, reading the source code, that all of them are present, but hidden, which means the template is being actually overriden.

Having a look into the `eav_attribute` table, I found that all the fields has the field `is_required` set to `1` (which makes sense) but four of seven fields are twice, with the `entity_type_id` field set to `1` and `2` (`customer` and `customer_address`, according to `eav_entity_type` table).

The `install-1.0.0.1.php` script has a `visible_on_front` field set to `1` too (which is not present in the `eav_attribute`).

I don't get how a form field can be disabled (or hidden) but still being requested. So, the question is: how I make visible those custom fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! the problem was another XML layout file being located in `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\` and pointing to a non-existant template, which Magento was using all the time.

The right location of the right layout XML file is `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\` (which Magento was ignoring to).